# How to open an known URL directely, open a drive document by menu?

Tags: google-apps-script

This methode is Obsolete

How to acces directely and open a drive document by menu 
      URL or ID ?

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu with some items, some separators, and a sub-menu.
      DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('OAR')

      .addItem('MAJ  Date + OAR', 'test')
      .addItem('MAJ  Date  Auto', 'testdate')
     ***.addItem('Accès Direct URL', 'href=/d/1udvLSpaZNgalg6NId JMJvkkw3i9oCaEKa-A_CAC79CYkvsZKD545dyZN/edit?')***

       .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge  .I don't want to use widget .I want to open an url "URL" by menu + function on my googledoc document . One click to find ID of Active document and open an URL ( always the same document googledoc document on the drive) write a variable "a phrase of the active document" on the new document open "URL"

Comment: You should comment on my answer if you want me to be notified...that said, anchor widget is the only way to create a link:  a sidebar or a pop up...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it from a menu item.

But you can do it from a sidebar that can automatically be opened with your document of from a popup triggered by a menu call.

Use [UiApp anchor widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/anchor) (plenty of examples around here...)

Comment: Thanks Serge .Your solution works only on spreadsheet i presume my problem is that i have a Document .I don't want to use widget .I want to open an url "URL" by menu + function on my googledoc document . One click to find ID of Active document and open an URL ( always the same document googledoc document on the drive) write a variable "a phrase of the active document" on the new document open "URL"

Comment: Ce service est devenu Obsolete . Comment peut on le remplacer ?

Comment: Vous pouvez utiliser le HTML service, you'll have to use de <a> tag to redirect to any URL. See the HTML tag documentation for details.

Comment: And please note that this forum is using English exclusively ;)